# How to handle array of void pointers

Tags: c, pointers, void

I would like to get a reference to an element at position in an array of void pointers. This is my function, I don't know if am doing it correctly. I have these two functions:

```
typedef struct vector 
{
  void **array;
  size_t size;
}vector;
```

I believe this gets the reference to the element at position pos.

```
void **get_at(vector *this, size_t pos) 
{
   assert(pos >=0 && pos < this->size);

   return &this->array[pos];
}
```

I believe this gets the pointer to the element at position pos.

```
void *at(vector *this, size_t pos) 
{
   assert(pos >=0 && pos < this->size);

   return this->array[pos];
}
```

I just would like to know if am correct with this implementation.

Just one more question:
If I want to destroy the array, is doing it this way enough? Do I have to loop through the array elements freeing the memory held by each element?

```
void destroy(vector *this)
{
  free(this->array);
  free(this);
}
```

Comment: Functions "get_at" and "at" look OK to me, but destroy needs to make sure all the void pointers in the this->array are disposed properly: first "free" each one of them, and then free "this"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have to loop through the array elements freeing the memory held by each element?

This is something only you can know.

There is a notion of ownership that is pervasive in all languages that support manual memory management. Every object is owned by some other object (or maybe by a group of objects but that's a bit more involved). When the owner dies, all objects owned by it die too.

We tend to personify the objects a bit, so you will often hear questions like "who owns this?". This "who" refers to an object, not to a person.

You have a vector of pointers that point to a bunch of objects. Who owns these objects? This is up to you to decide.

If the vector itself is the owner, then it will be a good idea to free the objects when the array itself is freed. Note that freeing an object may be a bit more involved than just calling `free()` (just imagine that each of these objects is *another* vector). This is why a good vector would look something like this:

```
typedef struct vector 
{
  void **array;
  size_t size;
  void (*destroy)(void*); // call this for each object
                          // when freeing the vector
} vector;
```

You assign the `destroy` member when you initialise your vector.

Your destroy function would look like this:

```
void destroy(vector *this)
{
  if (this->destroy) 
    for (int i = 0; i < this->size; ++i) 
      this->destroy(this->array[i]);
  free(this->array);
  free(this);
}
```

If your vector doesn't own objects it points to, it shouldn't try to destroy them. This `vector` implementation works in this case too, just assign a null pointer to `this->destroy`.

You should design a coherent ownership structure for your program. There are no universal recipes.

---

`get_at` and `at` look OK as is.

Comment: @Calvince please, consider accepting n.m.'s explanation as an answer to your question.

Comment: When I loop over the array of elements and try deleting each element, I get an error,  `munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer` but if just call the `free(this->array)` it just works fine

Comment: @Calvince There is a bug in your program somewhere. My crystal ball is unfortunately out for maintenance, so I cannot tell you where exactly.